# Rails path tags conflicting, want urls like /post/some-title but when editing/updating use the ID not title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having some issues, I want my urls for the show action to be like:

```
/post/some-title
```

i.e. so wherever I reference the show_post_path tag (or whatever it is) it should make that url.

BUT, when editing/updating I want to do this using the ID of the post ie.

```
/post/234/edit
```

How can I achieve this, it seems what I am doing is messing things up because I used:

```
def to_param
  #{title}"
end
```

In my post model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always add an attribute called 'slug' to posts and it acts as a slug for that post.
Then just find your posts with `Post.find_by_slug(params[:id])`.
You can even make it translatable.

Comment: yes, but how do I use a tag helper to wrap this logic? using the ones in my routes file won't work will it?

Comment: def post_path_for(post); post_path(:id => post.slug); end

Comment: I add this as a helper or in the model?

Answer (score 1):

Create a to_param method. For example:

```
def to_param
  "#{self[:id]}-#{title.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]+/i, '-')}"
end
```

Assuming the field you wanted to be in the URL is title, then your posts' URLs would be like /posts/1-this-is-a-post.